# How do I simulate a projector using Python and the module pyglet?

Tags: python, pyglet, projector

I would like to have an image or video projected onto many surfaces which are varying distances from the projector and varying shapes.

Is there an straight forward way to do this with pyglet?

Edit: https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Projected_Textures I would like something similar to what panda3d can do with a "simulated projector".

Comment: Poor question at the moment. Can you show some example of what you are trying to achieve? A diagram perhaps? Do you have any code written so far?

Comment: For example, imagine I have a cube and a sphere on a table, and I point a projector playing a movie at it. Each of the objects will be illuminated with the projection, but the image will be warped.How do I map textures onto objects based on a simulated projection of an image?